# How pass the TempData in ExceptionFilterAttribute in Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have tried to create the `Exception filter` for my controller in Asp.Net Core MVC like this:

```
public class ControllerExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    public ControllerExceptionFilterAttribute(
        IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }

    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        //How construct a temp data here which I want to pass to error page?
        var result = new ViewResult
        {
            ViewName = "Error"
        };

        context.ExceptionHandled = true; // mark exception as handled
        context.Result = result;
    }
}
```

I need in `OnException`method work with `TempData`- how can I set some exception information to `TempData`in this place? I have used this TempData to some notification.

There is missing something like this: `context.Controller.TempData["notification"]` - Controller property was probable removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve what you're looking for with the [`ITempDataDictionaryFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures.itempdatadictionaryfactory?view=aspnetcore-2.0), which you can take into your constructor via dependency injection. This has a single function, [`GetTempData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures.itempdatadictionaryfactory.gettempdata?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ViewFeatures_ITempDataDictionaryFactory_GetTempData_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_HttpContext_), which can be used for accessing what you refer to as `TempData`. Here's a complete example to suit your needs:

```
public class ControllerExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;
    private readonly ITempDataDictionaryFactory _tempDataDictionaryFactory;

    public ControllerExceptionFilterAttribute(
        IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment,
        ITempDataDictionaryFactory tempDataDictionaryFactory)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
        _tempDataDictionaryFactory = tempDataDictionaryFactory;
    }

    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        //How construct a temp data here which I want to pass to error page?
        var tempData = _tempDataDictionaryFactory.GetTempData(context.HttpContext);

        var result = new ViewResult
        {
            ViewName = "Error"
        };

        context.ExceptionHandled = true; // mark exception as handled
        context.Result = result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to pass the model from ExceptionContext to ViewResult? I want to return back to View if is Exception type of UIException.